# Chrome browser Web Speech API SpeechRecognition() only understands English (implementation of `lang` property)

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

My implementation of Web Speech API SpeechRecognition() in Chrome works great when I'm speaking English but in other languages it often returns English words. Did I implement `this.recognition.lang` incorrectly? The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/lang) gives only a basic example.

Does `this.recognition.lang` belong in `init()` or in `start()`? Maybe I'm initializing SpeechRecognition() with English (the default) and the failing to tell it when the user switches to another language?

```js
init() {
    this.recognition.interimResults = true;
    switch (this.language2!.short) {
      case 'en':
        this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
        break;
      case 'es':
        this.recognition.lang = 'es-ES';
        break;
      case 'fr':
        this.recognition.lang = 'fr-FR';
        break;
      case 'de':
        this.recognition.lang = 'de-DE';
        break;
      case 'it':
        this.recognition.lang = 'it-IT';
        break;
      case 'pt':
        this.recognition.lang = 'pt-PT';
        break;
      case 'ru':
        this.recognition.lang = 'ru-RU';
        break;
      case 'zh':
        this.recognition.lang = 'zh-CN';
        break;
      case 'fi':
        this.recognition.lang = 'fi-FI';
        break;
      default:
        this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
        break;
    }
    this.recognition.continuous = false;
    this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e: any) => {
      const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
        .map((result: any) => result[0])
        .map((result) => result.transcript)
        .join('');
      this.tempWords = transcript;
      this.speechRecognitionWait = false;
    });
  }

  start() {
    try {
      this.recognition.start();
      this.speechRecognitionStart = true;
      this.isStoppedSpeechRecog = false;
      this.speechRecognitionWait = true;
    } catch (error) { // doesn't prevent error "Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started"
      this.recognition.stop();
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few logs and, indeed, I was initializing SpeechRecognition() with English and switching my app to another language didn't switch the SpeechRecognition() language. This code works much better.

```js
init() {
    this.recognition.interimResults = true;
    this.recognition.continuous = false;
    this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e: any) => {
      const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
        .map((result: any) => result[0])
        .map((result) => result.transcript)
        .join('');
      this.tempWords = transcript;
      this.speechRecognitionWait = false;
    });
  }

  start() {
    try {
      switch (this.language2!.short) {
        case 'en':
          this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
          break;
        case 'es':
          this.recognition.lang = 'es-ES';
          break;
        case 'fr':
          this.recognition.lang = 'fr-FR';
          break;
        case 'de':
          this.recognition.lang = 'de-DE';
          break;
        case 'it':
          this.recognition.lang = 'it-IT';
          break;
        case 'pt':
          this.recognition.lang = 'pt-PT';
          break;
        case 'ru':
          this.recognition.lang = 'ru-RU';
          break;
        case 'zh':
          this.recognition.lang = 'zh-CN';
          break;
        case 'fi':
          this.recognition.lang = 'fi-FI';
          break;
        default:
          this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
          break;
      }
      this.recognition.start();
      this.speechRecognitionStart = true;
      this.isStoppedSpeechRecog = false;
      this.speechRecognitionWait = true;
    } catch (error) {
      this.recognition.stop();
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```